# The difference between List ::: operator and ++

Tags: list, scala, operators

What is the difference between scala `:::` and `++` operator? According to the [doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) the behaviour is the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala list concatenation, ::: vs ++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559996/scala-list-concatenation-vs)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

They do the same thing, except that `++` can be used with any `Traversable` and `:::` can only be used with lists. Also, methods that end with `:` are called on the object to the right, so that `:::`'s argument is the prefix while `++`'s argument is the suffix.

Comment: That's a bit confusing. One of them should be simply overloaded. Thx.

Comment: Ah, I see, @Kim. Right associativity and the use of ++ over any Traversable. That makes sense.

Answer (score 14):

The behavior is the same. The difference is in the types that they accept.

`:::` only accepts a `List`. `++` accepts is a range of types from `[B >: A, That]` meaning that `++` will accept a type whose lower bound is `List` and upper bound is `GenTraversableOnce[B]` and types in between.

So, in the type hierarchy diagram classes that extend trait `GenTraversableOnce` and are a supertype of `List` are valid

[image: List type hierarchy]

An example show this behavior using List and LinkedList.:

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val l2 = List(4,5,6)
l2: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6)

scala> l ++ l2
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

scala> l ::: l2
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

scala> import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList
import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList

scala> val ll = LinkedList(1,2,3)
ll: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[Int] = LinkedList(1, 2, 3)

scala> ll ++ l2
res2: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[Int] = LinkedList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

scala> ll ::: l2
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
found   : scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[Int]
required: List[?]
          ll ::: l2
```

Also, see Kim's note about associativity.

Comment: Is `A ::: B ::: C` equivalent to `A ++ B ++ C`, with regards to behavior? As far as I can tell, they are _not_ (order of operations). In that sense, the behavior is not the same..

Comment: but the outcome is associative, so it really is.

Answer (score 0):

@lukas, this post might be useful also. [How to interpret ::: from the Scala API for List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904505/how-to-interpret-from-the-scala-api-for-list/12911919#12911919)
The answers given by others to the question in that post (mine) helped ne understand what the ::: method does, although it does not contrast it with the ++ method. But I thought including this might help.